# Ember.js how to add belongsTo relationship?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have an Evaluation model in my EmberData, which has a belongsTo relationship with Thread model. I'd like to create a new thread and assign it to the Evalutation and then save it to backend. My code looks like this:

```
var thread = self.get("store").createRecord("thread", {
    title: self.get("thread_name"),    
    private: true      
});

thread.save().then(function() {
    var post = self.get("store").createRecord("post", {
        author: self.get("session.profile.id"),
        body: self.get("thread_content"),
        thread: thread,
        private: true
    });
    return post.save();
}).then(function() {
    // assign the realtionship - HERE is the problem
    self.set("model.comment", thread); // This call fails
    return self.get("model").save();
}
```

I am getting this unclear stacktrace...

```
post_thread/<@http://localhost:4200/assets/ksi.js:370:21
tryCatch@http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:64238:14
invokeCallback@http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:64253:15
publish@http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:64221:9
@http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:41059:7
Queue.prototype.invoke@http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:10314:9
Queue.prototype.flush@http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:10378:11
DeferredActionQueues.prototype.flush@http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:10178:11
Backburner.prototype.end@http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:9571:9
Backburner.prototype.run@http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:9639:13
run@http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:28889:12
ember$data$lib$adapters$rest$adapter$$RestAdapter<.ajax/</hash.success@http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:72687:15
jQuery.Callbacks/fire@http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:3301:10
jQuery.Callbacks/self.fireWith@http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:3413:7
done@http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:8466:5
.send/callback/<@http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:8807:1
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In your code block above, `this.set("model.comment, thread);` should be written as `this.get("model").set("comment", thread);` but the real issue is that your stack trace is unreadable (format it!) and you didn't post the actual error you're getting from the failing call to `set`.

Comment: Those two code blocks are equivalent. `set` accepts a path argument.

Comment: I am sorry for the mistakes I added, when I was shortening the code - I am using self instead of this. I have no other output from the code - this is what appears in the console. No other error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `self` instead of `this`:

```
var self = this; // I'm assuming you do this somewhere

thread.save().then(function() {
    ...
}).then(function() {
    // assign the realtionship - HERE is the problem
    self.set("model.comment", thread); // This call fails
    return self.get("model").save();
});
```